# Python/Maths: Convert a matrix into a lower triangular matrix

Tags: python, matrix, triangular

I defined the matrix a. Then I wrote an algorithm which turns the matrix a into a lower triangular matrix (I provided the programme below)

The algorithm does work because if I do "print(" ")" at the end of the algorithm I do receive a lower triangular matrix
But when I do "print(a)" directly afterwards (so after the algorithm for the lower triangular matrix)
I still receive the previous matrix a... and then it is not a lower triangular matrix. So I would like the matrix a to "permanently" be a lower triangular matrix, and not just whenever I use this algorithm (with the "print(" ")" at the end)

How can I sort of "change" the matrix a in a way that it stays a lower triangular matrix? I hope I expressed myself well.

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np 
s = 5

#s is the number of columns and rows respectively#

a = np.array([[None]*s]*s)

print(a)
#I receive a matrix with 5 columns/rows respectively#


#Calculates number of rows and columns present in given matrix#  
rows = len(a);  
cols = len(a[0]);  
   
if(rows != cols):  
    print("Matrix should be a square matrix");  
else:  
    #Performs required operation to convert given matrix into lower triangular matrix  
    print("Lower triangular matrix: ");  
    for i in range(0, rows):  
        for j in range(0, cols):  
            if(j > i):  
                print("0"),  
            else:  
                print(a[i][j]),  
      
        print(" ");  

#so far it works perfectly fine. If I use this algorithm I do receive a lower triangular matrix#

print(a)
    
#my wish was that now that I do print(a) again that it would print the matrix a but as a lower triangular matrix. because of the previous algorithm. but I get the same matrix as I did when I did "print(A)" for the first time.#type here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that `print`ing and assigning values to variables are different actions:

- `print` shows a message on the screen but does not change the value of any variable.
- Assignment, such as `x = 2` or `a[i][j] = 0` changes the value that is stored in that place in memory.

If you want to change the matrix, then you need to use the [assignment operator](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter02.01-Variables-and-Assignment.html#:%7E:text=The%20assignment%20operator%2C%20denoted%20by,be%20stored%20into%20this%20variable.) to change the values. In practice you just need to add `a[i][j] = 0` in the correct place.

```
if(j > i):
    a[i][j] = 0 # <-- add this line
    print("0"),
```

Now the elements in the upper right part will be set to zero.

Comment: Brilliant it worked… your explanation makes sense. thank you very much!

Comment: @sakabukayo You are welcome! Make sure to upvote and accept (green checkmark) the answer if it helped you to help future visitors. Good luck in your coding journey!